# Error: 1 is not a function [factorial, (anon), product, (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon)]

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I'm working through SICP on my own. The function `product` is intended to return the product of the values of a function at points over a given range, and I'm trying to use it to define a function that returns the factorial of a number However, the compiler keeps popping errors. The code is below:

```
(define (product term a next b)
  (define (iter result a)
    (if(> a b)
       result
       (* (term a)
          (iter (+ result (term a)) (next a)))))
  (iter 0 a))

(define (factorial x)
  (define (inc h)
    (+ h 1))
  (define (identity h)
    (h))
  (product identity 1 inc x)
)

(factorial 4)
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2):

In `identity`, `(h)` means *to call a function `h`*. But you just want to just return the value `h`.

The parentheses around `h` should be removed:

```
  (define (identity h)
     h )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not that familiar with the language itself.

Comment: Scheme's `(h)` is the same as `h()` in the more usual mainstream C-like languages. And `(h a b)` is like `h(a,b)`.